# Check if file is playable with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

Is there a method that one can use to determine if a file is playable by AVAudioPlayer? It would be easier than checking the filetype to a list of types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

refer a following code.

```
NSString *pathExtension = [audioFilePath pathExtension];
CFStringRef preferredUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (CFStringRef)pathExtension, NULL);
BOOL fileConformsToUTI = UTTypeConformsTo(preferredUTI, kUTTypeAudio);

if(fileConformsToUTI)
{
    NSLog(@"playable");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"not playable");
}
```

Comment: I need to check if it can be played without initializing the audio player object.